# Serve a different admin theme for a user role

Tags: 7, users, theming

I am making a news website. I want the administrator to have the default drupal 7 theme `Seven`. But I want to give the editor a custom theme that is more usable and streamlined for the task they do.

I have seen this module called [ThemeKey.](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) As far as I read it gives a lot of functions. For me as now only thing I want is when the user of the role editor login, they should be served with different admin theme. Thats all. Is there any hooks or something? Are there any examples or recommendations for achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this module does exactly what you need, I used it on a project and works very well

[Role theme switcher module](http://drupal.org/project/role_theme_switcher)

Comment: That switches the main theme, but does it switch the admin theme?

Comment: This is not asnwer ,this module can't change admin theme per roles .

Answer (score 2):

I like your question. However, I would follow a different approach. Rather than creating a whole new theme for editors,  I would add a unique class into the `classarray[] = 'newclassuserrole';` { page preprocessor } in the body element via user role and then write all my css like this

```
body.newclassforuserrole region content .. and so on  {}
```

I would create extra variables and regions to be used on certain pages like ['node/%node/edit']` etc

This way you can save extra php processing and can accomplish the theming part as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [Themes By Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/tbr) module works for your purpose; I don't think RTS does what you want.